# Existence of an antiderivative in $ U∪V $

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove the following:

> > Let $U,V \subset \mathbb C$ be open and connected sets such that $U \cap V $ is connected as well.
> >     Let $f$ be a holomorphic funtion with complex antiderivative on $U $and $V$. 
> > Then $f$ has a complex antiderivative on $U \cup V$.

Let $F_1$ be the antiderivative on $U $ and $F_2$ be the antiderivative on $V$ then $F_1^{'} =F_2^{'} $ on the conncted set $U\cap V$. 
Hence $F_1 = F_2+c$. 

I dont know how to get to get the antiderivative on $U\cup V$ from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the idea.  If you knew that $F_1=F_2$ on the intersection, then you could define an antiderivative $F$ on $U\cup V$ by just saying $F(z)=F_1(z)$ for $z\in U$ and $F(z)=F_2(z)$ for $z\in V$.  This is well-defined because $F_1(z)=F_2(z)$ if $z\in U\cap V$.

Unfortunately, you might not have $F_1=F_2$ on $U\cap V$.  But can you see a way you could modify $F_2$ such that this is true?

Comment: I can just use $ F = F_1 +c $ as the antiderivate on $U$ and the condition would be satisfied.